# display disabled series in legend

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, legend

I have a checkbox that allows my program to enable disable series displayed on my chart. When I disable the serie, it is removed from the chartArea and as well from the legend. Is it possible to keep it in the legend even if disabled? I'd like to change it's transparency in the legend so that it looks as disabled and set it back to full color on enabled.

Here's a link of what I am looking for:

http://postimage.org/image/kj675p14j/

Comment: are you using a 3rd party library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT :**

I found another (much simpler) way to do this. You can simply handle the `CustomizeLegend` event (and disable the series using `series.Enabled`):

```
void chart1_CustomizeLegend(object sender, CustomizeLegendEventArgs e)
{
    e.LegendItems.Clear();
    foreach (var series in this.chart1.Series)
    {
        var legendItem = new LegendItem();
        legendItem.SeriesName = series.Name;
        legendItem.ImageStyle = LegendImageStyle.Rectangle;
        legendItem.BorderColor = Color.Transparent;
        legendItem.Name = series.Name + "_legend_item";

        int i = legendItem.Cells.Add(LegendCellType.SeriesSymbol, "", ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter);
        legendItem.Cells.Add(LegendCellType.Text, series.Name, ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter);

        if (series.Enabled)
            legendItem.Color = series.Color;
        else
            legendItem.Color = Color.FromArgb(100, series.Color);
        e.LegendItems.Add(legendItem);
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: all series enabled]

[image: one series disabled]

Comment: When you use line charts setting the points color to transparent might help, but i have tried this example with a bar chart and setting points to transparent does not show the same result

Comment: That's what I wanted. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

With the example above expanded you can use *Tooltip* object shown/hidden in *MouseMove* event and trigger the *CustomizeLegend* event whenever the legends should animate/update. Clicking the legends will hide show each series.

```
private int lastX; private int lastY;
ToolTip tip = new ToolTip();

Chart.MouseMove += (object sender, MouseEventArgs e) =>
{

    //Cancel tooltip re-triggering itself when shown 
    if (e.X == this.lastX && e.Y == this.lastY)
    {
        return;
    }

    //Get any object clicked
    var hit = Chart.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);

    if (hit.Object is LegendItem legendItem)
    {
        tip.Tag = legendItem;
        tip.ToolTipTitle = legendItem.SeriesName;
        tip.Show(legendItem.ToolTip, Chart, new Point(e.X + Chart.Cursor.Size.Width / 2, e.Y + Chart.Cursor.Size.Height / 2));
        Chart.Legends[0].Enabled = true; //trigger CustomizeLegend event
    }
    else
    {
        if (tip.Active)
        {
            tip.UseFading = true;
            tip.Hide(Chart);
            tip.Tag = null;
            Chart.Legends[0].Enabled = true; //trigger CustomizeLegend event
        }
    }

    this.lastX = e.X;
    this.lastY = e.Y;
};
```

The *CustomizeLegend* event expanded to check tooltip .Tag for current legendItem howered

```
Chart.CustomizeLegend += (o, e) =>
{

    e.LegendItems.Clear();
    foreach (var series in this.Chart.Series)
    {
        var legendItem = new LegendItem();
        legendItem.Tag = series;
        legendItem.SeriesName = series.Name;
        legendItem.ImageStyle = LegendImageStyle.Rectangle;

        //Check if Tooltip as active for the legend
        if (tip.Tag is LegendItem tipLegendItem && legendItem.SeriesName.Equals(tipLegendItem.SeriesName))
        {
            //Show legend highlighted
            legendItem.ImageStyle = LegendImageStyle.Rectangle;
            legendItem.BorderColor = Color.Black;
            legendItem.BorderWidth = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            //Show legend normal
            legendItem.BorderColor = Color.Transparent;
        }

        legendItem.Name = series.Name + "_legend_item";
        legendItem.ToolTip = "on/off";

        int i = legendItem.Cells.Add(LegendCellType.SeriesSymbol, "", ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter);
        legendItem.Cells.Add(LegendCellType.Text, series.Name, ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft);

        //Show legend faint or active by state of Series.Enabled  
        if (series.Enabled) { 
            legendItem.Color = series.Color;
            legendItem.Cells[1].ForeColor = Color.Black;
        }
        else
        {
            legendItem.Color = Color.FromArgb(100, series.Color);
            legendItem.Cells[1].ForeColor = Color.LightGray;
        }

        e.LegendItems.Add(legendItem);
    }
};
```

And the *MouseDown* event to toggle Series.Enabled

```
Chart.MouseDown += (o, e) =>
{
    {
        HitTestResult result = Chart.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
                    
        // When user hits the LegendItem
        if (result?.Object is LegendItem legendItem)
        {
            if (legendItem.Tag is Series series )
            {
                series.Enabled = !series.Enabled;
                legendItem.ToolTip = series.Enabled ? "Enabled" : "Disabled";
                tip.Show(legendItem.ToolTip, Chart, new Point(e.X + Chart.Cursor.Size.Width / 2, e.Y + Chart.Cursor.Size.Height / 2));
            }
        }
    }
};
```